# Develop an app based on VSO API - Where can I find the database schema?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I started to work in an app which displays data coming via VSO API. It seems I have to use lots of custom query following [this](https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/wit/wiql) method.

The only issue I faced so far is the lack of available database schema. Do you know where can I find it? I have googled around and people says that there is a reason why it is not published. I should not access it directly. I do not want it. But, it seems this is the only way I have to get the data structure I need.

At the moment, I'm installing a TFS on my local machine in order to dump out the schema and write my queries.

Comment: If you're using VS Team Services, you're not going to be able to access the database anyway. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Ahh, after install I realized that I might mixed up the database schema with the object model. I'll investigate a bit more the situation and I'll update my question with the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I do not need the database schema. The fact I can run a query (WIQL) a bit confused me, I thought it is direct access to database. But, after I have spent more time to investigate what I want and how TFS works, I realized that database schema is not needed.

Basically, I was looking for the information can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb130306.aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitem.aspx).